# Sass width calculation based on class

Tags: html, css, sass

I'am playing with`mixins` and `for` loop in sass, and would like to ask what is the best approach to handle this case: I have class on UI that could be either or name based or index based. So let's dive to code.

className={cn('stepper', {`step-${activeIndex}`})}

**solution 1:**

```
$steps: (
  0: 0%,
  1: 33%,
  2: 66%,
  3: 99%,
);

@mixin step-modifiers {
  @each $name, $hex in $steps {
    &.step-#{$name} {
      width: $hex;
    }
  }
}

.stepper{
  @include step-modifiers;
}
```

**solution 2:**

```
$steps: 3;

@for $i from 0 through $steps {
  .step-#{$i} {
    width: (100% * $i / $steps);

  }
}
```

**Expected result**

```
.stepper.step-0 {
  width: 0%;
}
.stepper.step-1 {
  width: 33%;
}
.stepper.step-2 {
  width: 66%;
}
.stepper.step-3 {
  width: 99%;
}
```

Comment: `step-3` must be 99% or 100%? The 2 approaches you propose have slightly different results.

Comment: I my case it's does not matter, I just looking for a better solution and best practice to do that

Comment: I think both solutions are perfectly valid. The first one offers more customization options since the values are inside a map and thus are completely independent from each other. In the second example you calculate the values so this would be the cleaner solution if you do not want to edit each and every value but instead calculate them based on a formula and just one value for steps. In the second example you can achieve the same results as in your map by using the `floor()` function by the way ;)